# How can I remove an HtmlTableRow with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, hidden

I've got an HtmlTable that sports two rows by default, but can "grow" up to six with this code:

```
/* This makes the next hidden row visible, as long as there is one */
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=foapalhtmltable]').find('tr:hidden:first').show();
});
```

Actually, all six rows *are* created in the code-behind, but all but the first two are set to "display:none" - the code above exposes them one-by-one.

I also need to accomplish the opposite: if a user clicks the matching "-" button (btnRemoveFoapalRow), the last row should be hidden. How to do that? Here's pseudocode, which I'm sure is wrong in at least some of its particulars:

```
/* This removes the last displayed row, as long as there are more than two such */
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnRemoveFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=foapalhtmltable]').find('tr:displayed:last').hide();
});
```

Additionally, I need to prevent it from hiding the first two rows, which should always be visible. Is there a way to check the count of non-hidden rows and, if it is two or less, disallow further hiding?

Comment: You should try this and ask questions about specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Show us some html...we have no idea what `id$=foapalhtmltable` is. Very hard to filter precisely the way you are asking with no tree structure given

Comment: @pvg: I tried my pseudocode, and it hoses up everthing else (presumably because it makes no sense/doesn't "compile")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on an answer to one of your previous questions you can use:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnRemoveFoapalRow]', function (e) {
  if ($("[id$=foapalhtmltable] tr:visible").length > 2) {
     $('[id$=foapalhtmltable]').find('tr:visible:last').hide();
  }
});
```

It might also be an idea to show and hide the buttons when they are no longer useful. E.g if there you can't remove anymore rows, hide the collapse button.

On a side note `[id$=foapalhtmltable]` is a very inefficient selector, you would be much better off using the jQuery class selector (like in my snippet below) or handling ASP.net name mangling of id's and using the ID selector. E.g:

```
$(document).on("click", '#<%=btnRemoveFoapalRow.ClientId%>', function (e) {
```

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
  $('.inputTable').find('tr:hidden:first').show();
});


$(".collapser").click(function() {
  console.log($(".inputTable tr:visible").length);
  if ($(".inputTable tr:visible").length > 2) {
    $('.inputTable').find('tr:visible:last').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.inputTable tr:nth-child(n + 3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_btnAddFoapalRow" type="button" class="expander">+</button>
<button id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_btnAddFoapalRow" type="button" class="collapser">-</button>
<table border="2" class="inputTable">
  <tr>
    <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="dplatypus-webform-field-label">Index</span>
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="dplatypus-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Fund</span>
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="dplatypus-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Organization</span>
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="dplatypus-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Account</span>
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="dplatypus-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Activity</span>
    </td>
    <td width="88px" style="text-align:center;"><span class="dplatypus-webform-field-label" style="text-align:center;">Amount</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl130" type="text" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl132" type="text" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl134" type="text" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl136" type="text" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl138" type="text" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ctl140" type="text" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" style="width:88px;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_foapalrow3">
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxIndex2foapalrow3" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxIndex2foapalrow3" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxFund2foapalrow3" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxFund2foapalrow3" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxOrg2foapalrow3" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxOrg2foapalrow3" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxAccount2foapalrow3" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxAccount2foapalrow3" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxActivity2foapalrow3" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxActivity2foapalrow3" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxAmount2foapalrow3" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxAmount2foapalrow3" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_foapalrow4">
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxIndex3foapalrow4" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxIndex3foapalrow4" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxFund3foapalrow4" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxFund3foapalrow4" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxOrg3foapalrow4" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxOrg3foapalrow4" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxAccount3foapalrow4" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxAccount3foapalrow4" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxActivity3foapalrow4" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxActivity3foapalrow4" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
    <td width="88px">
      <input name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$boxAmount3foapalrow4" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_boxAmount3foapalrow4" class="dplatypus-webform-field-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be safe to say that you can use

```
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

to remove table rows. Use the code inside your onclick handler. Read up on this approach to find the correct table row in your particular scenario.

Comment: I don't want it in the ready handler; it needs to be in response to the button click.

Comment: I tried the code above - it cause the page to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from Jon P's answer, here's what seems to work best for me (works like a charm bracelet):

```
/* This removes the last displayed row, as long as there are more than two such*/
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnRemoveFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    if ($("[id$=foapalhtmltable] tr:visible").length > 2) {
        $('[id$=foapalhtmltable]').find('tr:visible:last').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you just want to hide and not to remove a table row?